# Why sbt executes redundant task?

Tags: sbt

Consider a simple sbt file:

```scala
lazy val task = taskKey[Unit]("task")

lazy val p = project.in(file(".")).settings(
  packageBin in Compile := {
    println("compile")
    (packageBin in Compile).value
  },
  task := {
    sys.props.get("conf") match {
      case Some(t) => println(t)
      case None => println((packageBin in Compile).value)
    }
  }
)
```

And two runs of sbt:

```sh
sbt task
[info] Set current project to p (in build file:...)
compile
.../target/scala-2.10/p_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 20, 2017 1:11:48 PM

sbt -Dconf=xxx task
[info] Set current project to p (in build file:...)
compile
xxx
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 20, 2017 1:13:39 PM
```

You can see that task compile is executed in both cases, thought it looks like it should be executed only in the first one.

My questions are:

1. Why it happens? I think that's because of implementation of macro value, but my understanding of scala macros and sbt internals is too low to explain why exactly.
2. Is there any workaround except definition of two different tasks?
3. Do I use wrong pattern relying on props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the `task` key is defined in terms of the `packageBin in Compile` key. So even if its value is only used in one branch of the code, it's effect (println) is executed in both.

The solution is to use taskDyn: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with